# How should i get the value from custom attribute in react element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is my html looks like.....

```
<select onclick={this.handleClick}>
    <option key="1" value="aaa" data-plan-id="test"></option>
</select>
```

Below is my handleClick event code

```
console.log(e.target.value);   // this will output aaa
```

My question is how can I get the value from "data-plan-id" attribute which is "test"??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just read `selectedOptions` HTMLCollection and take the first option from it:

```javascript
console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].getAttribute('data-plan-id'));
```

With modern browsers (IE11+, see [support](http://caniuse.com/#search=dataset)) you can use [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) interface instead of `getAttribute`:

```javascript
console.log(e.target.selectedOptions[0].dataset.planId);
```

Comment: Appreciate for help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through all the `<option>` of the `<select>` and check if the value are same. If yes, check for `dataset`. This will have `plan-id`.

Ps. Javascript will convert dashed data attribute to camelCase `plan-id -> planId`

Hope this helps!

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  constructor(){
    super()
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      component: 'A'
    }
  }
  onChange(e){
    [...e.target.childNodes].forEach((el) => { //convert HTML collection to array
      if(el.value === e.target.value) 
        console.log(el.dataset.planId)
    })
    this.setState({
      component: e.target.value
    })
  }
  
  render(){
    return <div>
      <select onChange={this.onChange} selected={this.state.component}>
        <option value="aaa" data-plan-id="a plan">A</option>
        <option value="bbb" data-plan-id="b plan">B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry for typo,, I did put onClick event in select tag and what i want is to get data-plan-id vlaue